# Verification of dates mySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to check that the steps of each project were done between the start and end dates of the project. (Write a query that allows a human to know if this is the case)

This is my code:

```
SELECT e.idetape,
       e.idprojet,
       e.datedebut,
       e.datefin
FROM   (SELECT idprojet,
               datedebut,
               datefin
        FROM   projet) AS p
       LEFT JOIN etapexprojet AS e
              ON e.datedebut < p.datedebut
                 AND e.datefin < p.datefin
ORDER  BY idprojet;
```

The table of EtapexProjet (There is other date inside the table EtapexProjet ):

```
+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+--+
| idEtape | idProjet |  dateDebut  |   dateFin    |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+--+
|       1 |        1 | 2011-07-01  | 2011-09-01   |  |
|       1 |        2 | 2012-05-01  |  2012-05-10  |  |
|       1 |        3 | 2011-11-01  |  2012-01-20  |  |
|       2 |        1 |             |              |  |
|       2 |        2 |             |              |  |
|       2 |        3 |             |              |  |
|       3 |        1 |             |              |  |
|       3 |        2 |             |              |  |
|       3 |        3 |             |              |  |
|       4 |        1 |             |              |  |
|       4 |        2 |             |              |  |
|       5 |        2 |             |              |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+--+
```

The table of Projet:

```
+----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+--+
| idProjet | idClient | nomProjet | dateDebut  |  dateFin   | idResponsable |  |
+----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+--+
|        1 |      321 | Devl.     | 2011-08-01 |            |          1876 |  |
|        2 |      321 | Maint.    | 2012-05-01 | 2012-07-23 |          2231 |  |
|        3 |      345 | Devl.2    | 2011-11-01 |            |          2231 |  |
+----------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+---------------+--+
```

My expected results is that to check/verify if the beginning and ending date of each idEtape is between the beginning date and the ending date of the projet its related.

Comment: @williammorotti please add expected output in formatted table also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't need to use a Derived Table (sub-select query), as you are not doing any sort of aggregation, etc on the `projet` table.
- I believe that you are only concerned with the `idetape` values which lie inside the `projet`'s `datedebut` and `datefin`.
- You can change `Left Join` to `Inner Join` due to above mentioned point.
- I have also increased the horizon of cases to check, as there is a possibility of `datefin` being `NULL` in either of the tables.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT e.idetape,
       e.idprojet,
       e.datedebut,
       e.datefin,
       p.datedebut AS projet_datedebut,
       p.datefin   AS projet_datefin
FROM   EtapexProjet AS e
       JOIN Projet AS p
         ON p.idprojet = e.idprojet
            AND e.datedebut >= p.datedebut 
            AND (e.datefin <= p.datefin OR 
                 p.datefin IS NULL OR 
                 e.datefin IS NULL
                )
ORDER  BY e.idprojet, 
          e.idetape;
```

Comment: This is not working since it show only idEtape thats started BEFORE the projet date.

Comment: @williammorotti I think you want this only, right ? To get all the ideTape values which are outside the range

Comment: I want idEtape that is between the idProjet lenght of time. Then, my idEtape (1,2,3) of idProjet 1 is inside the idProjet 1 lenght of time. However, this code doesnt show this.

Comment: I withdraw the NOT from Between and this works only for the projet #2

Comment: the only problem is that it only works for projet #2, but not for the others projets (1 & 3) because of the NULL value in the dateFin column.

Comment: its still show only projet 2. I try putting OR e.datefin is NULL after the first AND statement, but it shows multiple times the same idEtape for a single idProjet

Comment: @williammorotti pls use my query exactly and let me know. Do you have a SQL or DB fiddle created for this ? Or, can you give me Show Create Table statement results, so that I can reproduce this problem in my local machine and test

Comment: I use SQL and this is the SHOW CREATE TABLE statement results:                                
     etapexProjet | CREATE TABLE `etapexProjet` (
     `idEtape` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `idProjet` int(11) NOT NULL,
     `dateDebut` date NOT NULL,
     `dateFin` date DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`idEtape`,`idProjet`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
     COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

Comment: Please check this link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/  Can you prepare a demo please, so that I can test and fix the query If possible

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
SELECT nomEtape, livrable, idEtape, idProjet 
FROM Etape 
WHERE idEtape= (SELECT MAX(idEtape) 
                FROM EtapexProjet 
                WHERE DISTINCT(idProjet)
               );
```